# Determine age of items in group_concat MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Is it possible, in a query, to determine age from dates contained inside a group_concat? Perhaps combining the following?

```
group_concat(children.age)

TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, age, CURDATE())
```

Or do I need to handle in PHP?

Comment: Can you do this: group_concat(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,children.age, CURDATE())) ?

Comment: No, I had tried that but it fails

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "to determine age from dates"? You want to get a list of birth dates from a list of ages?

Comment: The field children.age represents DATE, so 2001-09-09. I want to show the age, which I can do with a single date no problem, but once I group those dates into group_concat I,m not sure how to turn the date (2001-09-09) to the age (14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works on my table where id is an INT and age is a DATE:

```
SELECT id, group_concat(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,age, CURDATE())) FROM test4
group by id
```

Comment: You are right. Thanks a million. I had a few other things going on that I needed to address and simplified, that works.